# Is it possible to trim an image and force its dimensions to be even with ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick

Is it possible to trim image (say PNG with alpha) with command line version of ImageMagick in such a way that both width and height of output image will be even (not odd)?

To be precise, the output image should be first trimmed and then padded with transparent pixels. I need this for sprite sheet packing so after all necessary operations I would like to access stored 'Page geometry' or 'Origin geometry' (also avaiable as `%[fx:page.x]` `%[fx:page.y]` format variables).

I understand this can be achieved with extensive shell/batch scripting but frankly I am looking for smart one-liner.

Comment: I'll bid 4 lines of shell... 1 to get width and height, 1 to round width, 1 to round height, 1 to resize.

Comment: I'll improve my bid to 2 lines of `bash`... 1 to get width and height plus 1 to resize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

It seems you want the image padded, rather than trimmed or resized, so you can do that using `-extent` as you say in the comments:

```
convert image.png -background orange -extent  $(convert image.png -format '%[fx:2*int((w+1)/2)]x%[fx:2*int((h+1)/2)]!' info:) result.png
```

If you would like the image padded with transparent pixels, instead of my rather stylish orange ones (!), change `orange` to `none`.

As the default `-gravity` is NorthWest, this will pad to the right and bottom. If you would like to pad to the left and top, for example, use `-gravity SouthEast` before the `-extent`.

---

**Original Answer**

Untested, but should work...

This will get you the new dimensions:

```
convert image.png -format '%[fx:2*int((w+1)/2)]x%[fx:2*int((h+1)/2)]!' info:
```

So you need to do:

```
convert image.png -resize $(COMMAND ABOVE) result.png
```

Comment: This code resizes the image and I wanted it to remain in original size yet with larger canvas. I'll take the blame as I wasn't precise enough in my question. Nevertheless it helped me as we can change `-resize` to `-extent`.

Comment: Please have another look - I added some more useful stuff.

Comment: Thanks, that should do it! I have upgraded IM to v7 and I am quite certain that now it can parse FX expressions in other parameters. So `magick image.png -background orange -extent "%[fx:2*int((w+1)/2)]x%[fx:2*int((h+1)/2)]!" result.png` would also work. Unfortunatly I cannot get it done with mogrify.